# Boto3: aws credentials with limited permissions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I was provisioned some AWS keys. These keys give me access to certain directories in a s3 bucket.  I want to use `boto3` to interact with the directories that were exposed to me, however it seems that I can't actually do anything with the bucket at all, since I don't have access to the entire bucket.

This works for me from my terminal:

```
aws s3 ls s3://the_bucket/and/this/specific/path/
```

but if I do:

```
aws s3 ls s3://the_bucket/
```

I get:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects
>   operation: Access Denied

which also happens when I try to access the directory via `boto3`.

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name=my_creds)
client=session.client('s3')
list_of_objects = client.list_objects(Bucket='the_bucket', Prefix='and/this/specific/path', Delimiter='/')
```

Do I need to request access to the entire bucket for `boto3` to be usable?

Comment: Do you have access to the IAM Policy? You don't have permissions to list the objects in the bucket but you likely have access to getting certain objects by key (listing and getting are distinct permissions). I can't say for sure without seeing the policy though.

Comment: Also, you can't give ListObjects on an ARN including more than just the bucket.  It can further be restricted with a condition, but you allow  _list_ on the buckets, and  _get_ objects on an arn with prefix or key.

Comment: Please include a copy of the IAM Policy in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this Bucket Policy:

```
{
  "Sid": "<SID>",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account>:user/<user_name>"
  },
  "Action": [
    "s3:GetBucketLocation",
    "s3:ListBucket"
  ],
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>"
}
```

[For more information about Specifying Permissions in a Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html)